# Mock Javascript AWS.RDS.Signer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-mock

I have Connection class that is used to connect to AWS Rds Proxy via IAM Authentication. Part of that process is to create a token. I have a function to create the token but now I having a hard time to mock and test it.

Here is the Connection class with `setToken` method:

```
class Connection {
    constructor(username, endpoint, database) {
        this.username = username;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        this.database = database;
    }

    setToken () {
        let signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
            region: 'us-east-1', // example: us-east-2
            hostname: this.endpoint,
            port: 3306,
            username: this.username
        });

        this.token = signer.getAuthToken({
            username: this.username
        });
    }
}
```

And here I am trying to mock the return value of `AWS.RDS.Signer.getAuthToken()`

```
test('Test Connection setToken', async () => {
    AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
    AWSMock.mock('RDS.Signer', 'getAuthToken', 'mock-token');


    let conn = new connections.Connection(
        'testUser',
        'testEndpoint',
        'testDb');

    conn.setToken();

    console.log(conn.token);
});
```

I expected to see "mock-token" as the value for `conn.token`, but what I get is this:

```
{
  promise: [Function],
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream],
  on: [Function: on],
  send: [Function: send]
}
```

How can I get `AWS.RDS.Signer.getAuthToken()` to return a mock token?

---

**Edit after trying solution from @ggordon**

I have tried to get this to work by injecting `AWS` into the constructor, but still seem to be having the same issue. I think part of my problem is that AWS.RDS.Signer does not support promises, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is my new code:

The `Token` class which generates the token.
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

```
class Token {
    constructor(awsInstance) {
        this.awsInstance = awsInstance || AWS;
    }

    getToken () {
        const endpoint = 'aurora-proxy.proxy.rds.amazonaws.com';

        const signer = new this.awsInstance.RDS.Signer({
            region: 'my-region',
            hostname: endpoint,
            port: 3306,
            username: 'myUser'
        });

        const token = signer.getAuthToken({
                username: 'svcLambda'
            });

        console.log ("IAM Token obtained\n");
        return token
    }
}

module.exports = { Token };
```

And the test:

```
test('Should test getToken from Token', async () => {
    AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
    AWSMock.mock('RDS.Signer', 'getAuthToken', 'mock-token');

    let tokenObject = new tokens.Token(AWS);
    const token = tokenObject.getToken();

    console.log(token);
    expect(token).toStrictEqual('mock-token');
});
```

The Token class itself works -- it creates the token and the token can be used to make a successful connection to RDS. However, the unit test fails with the actual token returned (from console.log) being this:

```
{
  promise: [Function],
  createReadStream: [Function: createReadStream],
  on: [Function: on],
  send: [Function: send]
}
```

Also here is the `package.json` as requested by @GSSWain

```
{
  "name": "mylambda",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My description.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js __tests__/**/*.js",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/**/*.js __tests__/**/*.js",
    "prettier:ci": "prettier --list-different src/**/*.js  __tests__/**/*.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "test:coverage": "cross-env CI=true jest --coverage --watchAll=false -u --reporter=default --reporters=jest-junit",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.552.0",
    "aws-sdk-mock": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.19.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-junit": "^10.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sinon": "^9.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 100,
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100
      }
    }
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "outputName": "junit_jest.xml"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the package.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The `AWS` instance/object in your test scope is different from the `AWS` instance/object being used in your `setToken` method.

[`aws-sdk-mock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) mocks this instance

> Due to transpiling, code written in TypeScript or ES6 may not correctly mock because the aws-sdk object created within aws-sdk-mock will not be equal to the object created within the code to test.

Also `require` will return a new instance.

In essence you are mocking an instance in your test while your actual code is using another instance that has not been mocked.

### Possible Solutions

#### Solution 1

You could modify your code to allow you to optionally inject the desired `AWS` instances to use eg

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
class Connection {
    constructor(username, endpoint, database,awsInstance) {
        this.username = username;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        this.database = database;
        //if the awsInstance is null  or not provided use the default
        this.awsInstance = awsInstance || AWS;
    }

    setToken () {
        let signer = new this.awsInstance.RDS.Signer({
            region: 'us-east-1', // example: us-east-2
            hostname: this.endpoint,
            port: 3306,
            username: this.username
        });

        this.token = signer.getAuthToken({
            username: this.username
        });
    }
}
```

your code would not need any modifications, however now you can optionally in your tests

```
test('Test Connection setToken', async () => {
    AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
    AWSMock.mock('RDS.Signer', 'getAuthToken', 'mock-token');


    let conn = new connections.Connection(
        'testUser',
        'testEndpoint',
        'testDb',
        AWS //pass mock instance
        );

    conn.setToken();
    let actualToken = (await conn.token.promise());

    console.log(conn.token);
    console.log(actualToken);
});
```

This is only constructor based injection, you could inject it by doing similar in the `setToken` method.

You will also notice that in the examples provided by `aws-sdk-mock` and the example above we've extracted the result from the `promise` object returned. This is because the [mock implementation](https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/blob/master/index.js#L118) returns a promise object despite the fact that the `aws-sdk` especially for the [`AWS.RDS.Signer.getAuthToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS/Signer.html) supports synchronous operations. **This is a constraint based on the library you are using.**

#### Solution 2

You may want to consider another mocking library if you are interested in synchronous calls which based on the examples shared here would better mimic your code/flow. The other alternative is to consider an asynchronous/promise rewrite of your implementations. I leave this decision to you.

A simple alternative could be:

```
test('Test Connection setToken', async () => {
    AWS.RDS.Signer = function MockSigner() {
        return {
            getAuthToken: function MockGetAuthToken(){ return 'mock-token'; }
        };
    };


    let conn = new connections.Connection(
        'testUser',
        'testEndpoint',
        'testDb',
        AWS //pass mock instance
        );

    conn.setToken();

    console.log(conn.token);
});
```

### Additional References

I've included a snippet of the method used to mock functions for the `aws-sdk-mock` retrieved from https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/blob/master/index.js#L118 . You'll see that it creates and returns a `request`

```
function mockServiceMethod(service, client, method, replace) {
  services[service].methodMocks[method].stub = sinon.stub(client, method).callsFake(function() {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    let userArgs, userCallback;
    if (typeof args[(args.length || 1) - 1] === 'function') {
      userArgs = args.slice(0, -1);
      userCallback = args[(args.length || 1) - 1];
    } else {
      userArgs = args;
    }
    const havePromises = typeof AWS.Promise === 'function';
    let promise, resolve, reject, storedResult;
    const tryResolveFromStored = function() {
      if (storedResult && promise) {
        if (typeof storedResult.then === 'function') {
          storedResult.then(resolve, reject)
        } else if (storedResult.reject) {
          reject(storedResult.reject);
        } else {
          resolve(storedResult.resolve);
        }
      }
    };
    const callback = function(err, data) {
      if (!storedResult) {
        if (err) {
          storedResult = {reject: err};
        } else {
          storedResult = {resolve: data};
        }
      }
      if (userCallback) {
        userCallback(err, data);
      }
      tryResolveFromStored();
    };
    const request = {
      promise: havePromises ? function() {
        if (!promise) {
          promise = new AWS.Promise(function (resolve_, reject_) {
            resolve = resolve_;
            reject = reject_;
          });
        }
        tryResolveFromStored();
        return promise;
      } : undefined,
      createReadStream: function() {
        if (replace instanceof Readable) {
          return replace;
        } else {
          const stream = new Readable();
          stream._read = function(size) {
            if (typeof replace === 'string' || Buffer.isBuffer(replace)) {
              this.push(replace);
            }
            this.push(null);
          };
          return stream;
        }
      },
      on: function(eventName, callback) {
      },
      send: function(callback) {
      }
    };

    // different locations for the paramValidation property
    const config = (client.config || client.options || _AWS.config);
    if (config.paramValidation) {
      try {
        // different strategies to find method, depending on wether the service is nested/unnested
        const inputRules =
          ((client.api && client.api.operations[method]) || client[method] || {}).input;
        if (inputRules) {
          const params = userArgs[(userArgs.length || 1) - 1];
          new _AWS.ParamValidator((client.config || _AWS.config).paramValidation).validate(inputRules, params);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        callback(e, null);
        return request;
      }
    }

    // If the value of 'replace' is a function we call it with the arguments.
    if (typeof replace === 'function') {
      const result = replace.apply(replace, userArgs.concat([callback]));
      if (storedResult === undefined && result != null &&
          typeof result.then === 'function') {
        storedResult = result
      }
    }
    // Else we call the callback with the value of 'replace'.
    else {
      callback(null, replace);
    }
    return request;
  });
}
```

Comment: This still does not work for me. `console.log` outputs an object rather than the 'mock-token' string. However I tried with console.log(conn.token.promise() and the output was { 'mock-token' }. And it fails the unit test `expect(token).toStrictEqual('mock-token');`  with `Expected: "mock-token"
Received: {}`

Comment: The docs for `aws-sdk-mock` and a brief code review shows that aws-mock always returns a promise object and hence the examples with promises, please use `expect(await token.promise()).toStrictEqual('mock-token')` in your tests.

Comment: @navig8tr This library mocks all functions to return a promise - see implementation - (https://github.com/dwyl/aws-sdk-mock/blob/master/index.js#L118

Comment: @navig8tr I've also added a simple mocked synchronous override for consideration

Comment: Most of our platform uses asynchronous functions. Thats why the aws-sdk-mock library was chosen. I may take your suggestion to do an asynchronous/promise rewrite of my implementation. I'm very new to Javascript and promises so thats why i did not do it originally.